# Populate the chart with values returned by controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have created a C# asp.net MVC application. The controller is displayed below. I am using high charts and i want to populate the chart with what is returned by the controller.

There are 2 fields below, Mon and Tue, and i need to populate the hard coded values in the javascript below to display the values returned by the controller;

Note: I am not sure if the controller method works :( (I'm a beginner), but i am more concerned about how to populate the chart with the values returned by the controller.

My C# controller;

```
    public string timeHour()
    {
        var m = new MyModel();

        m.theTime = getAllTime(); // get all time

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(m);
    }
```

The High Chart that i have it in the view;

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'areaspline'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'some title'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 150,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Mon',
                    'Tue'
                ],
                plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
                    from: 4.5,
                    to: 6.5,
                    color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                areaspline: {
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [3, 4]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Two questions (1) What client-side event causes the controller to be called? (2) What does `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(m);` return?

Comment: 1.) It could be a GET or a POST (I want to know how to do this)2.) The return type is string

Comment: You haven't answered either question.

Comment: May be its because i am a beginner and i don't know what you are asking. Basically my question is how to populate the chart with values returned from a Controller. There's a problem in my controller as well, which i am looking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would change the Controller's return type from `string` to `JsonResult`.  To have your Controllers return ActionResults is a good MVC-style convention, and it makes your code a little more descriptive.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult timeHour()
{
    var m = new MyModel();
    m.theTime = getAllTime(); // get all time
    return Json(m, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

I believe that `GET` and `POST` requests should both work for you.  It sort of looks like `getallTime()` is idempotent (although the code isn't shown here), so it looks like a `GET` request should work. This can be done in jQuery using the [.get() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$(function () {
    $.get("timeHour", null, function(result) {
        console.log("If the GET request is successful, the Controller will return the HighCharts data:");
        console.log(result);
    }, "json");
});
```

You're going to need to make sure that the JSON returned to the client is in a format that Highcharts likes.  Now that the Controller is successfully called (via an AJAX GET request) and the Highcharts data is returned, your second question can be answered:

> how to populate the chart with the values returned by the controller

... via the [Highcharts "series.data" documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data).  If you read this, I think you can figure out how you'd need to change the `MyModel` object to suit your needs.